# Hiding views in Listview item android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

i have a simple Listview item as shown below.

[image]

It has got 4 textviews and 1 imageview

In This, some of the listview items does not have data related to Textview 2, Textview 3 i.e it comes as Empty or NULL.

So, if i set NULL or empty to textview it looks blank and seems like there is lot of gap between the items.

i tried by hiding the Textviews by setting `VISIBLITY GONE` property, but if i scroll it will create issue.

If All these items are arranged in relative layout, then again it wont arrange properly :(

How to handle these senarios?.

Comment: post your XML code and if custom Adapter than also post it

Comment: Show us what you have implemented till now, so we can help you out

Answer (score 0):

ListView works by reusing views as you scroll and reassigning elements to different views.  This means in the getView function you must reset ANY value that may change between two positions, including their visibility.  So you must remember what the visibility should be for each position (or be able to recalculate) and explicitly set it to VISIBLE if its VISIBLE or GONE if its GONE.

Comment: So, setting Visibility VIEW GONE property at runtime in adapter is the only one solution for this?

Comment: The adaptor needs to set the element to both VISIBLE and GONE, whichever it needs to be.  If you only have it set elements which are GONE you'll continue to have the same problem.  Lets say you set an image in row 0 to GONE.  When you scroll, row row 0 is now position 1 instead of position 0.  If you don't explicitly set it to VISIBLE, it will stay GONE because the view is reused.

Comment: So, we cant use relative layout if we do like this, because in relative layout we mention item with property layout_below, layout_above etc.. so if there are 3 rows and middle one i need to hide then how the last row will understand it should be below the middle one, because we have already hidden the middle one?.

Comment: No, you can use relative layouts in there.  Setting a view to gone shouldn't screw up a relative layout, Android still knows where it is.  A view just has 0 height and width when its GONE.